# How to configure collectd daemon sample rate for write graphite plugin

Tags: graphite

We have configured collectd to collect data from oracle,and collectd writes data to our graphite every 10 seconds. We should be able to configue this sample rate in collectd's configuration or can i configure write_graphite plugin . I am facing issue of data loss for some data points.
Please suggest if we can add any property in configuration problem.
Here is our sample configuration block for write_graphite plugin.

```
<Plugin write_graphite>
  <Carbon>
    Host "localhost"
    Port "2003"
    Prefix "collectd."
#    Postfix "collectd"
    StoreRates false
    AlwaysAppendDS false
    EscapeCharacter "_"
  </Carbon>
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly broad question, but in general according to the man page for collectd.conf, you can either change the global Interval setting in collectd.conf, or you can set it per plugin by making LoadPlugin a block:

```
<LoadPlugin write_graphite>
  Interval 5
</LoadPlugin>
```

Comment: As I am having some data loss of datapoints,let me try this and see how it works.

Comment: That option is not valid for that plugin. I tried to use it but it showed an error on "syslog" saying it was not a valid option for that plugin